# where i am wrong to get desire result in this python program?

Tags: python, function, percentage

This program is for my own practice purpose. This program has to calculate percentage of two list(5 numbers in each) and compare. The numbers will be entered by user.

```py
def percentage(mark):
    percentage = (((sum(mark))/500)*100)
    return percentage

mark1=[]
for j in range (1,6):
    a=int(input(f'Enter mark{j}: '))
    mark1.append(a)
    percentage1=percentage(mark1)

mark2=[]
for i in range(1,6):
    b=int(input(f'enter mark{i}: '))
    mark2.append(a)
    percentage2=percentage(mark2)

print(f'percentage of boy 1 is {percentage1} and boy 2 is {percentage2}')

if percentage1 > percentage2:
    print('Boy 1 is topper')
else: 
    print ('boy 2 is topper')
```

Comment: I presume you're using python 2 which would make your second line return an integer in your division

Comment: You didn't say what the code is supposed to do, what input you gave, or what the actual and expected outputs are. Which makes this unanswerable except by guessing.

Comment: mark2=[]
for i in range(1,6):
    b=int(input(f'enter mark{i}: '))
    mark2.append(a)
    percentage2=percentage(mark2).   you should append (b). it should be mark2.append(b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should appand the second input to the second mark, not the first input.

```
def percentage(mark):
    percentage = (((sum(mark))/500)*100)
    return percentage

mark1=[]
for j in range (1,6):
    a=int(input(f'Enter mark{j}: '))
    mark1.append(a)
    percentage1=percentage(mark1)

mark2=[]
for i in range(1,6):
    b=int(input(f'enter mark{i}: '))
    mark2.append(b)                    # <--- append b, not a !!
    percentage2=percentage(mark2)

print(f'percentage of boy 1 is {percentage1} and boy 2 is {percentage2}')

if percentage1 > percentage2:
    print('Boy 1 is topper')
else:
    print ('boy 2 is topper')
```